# O que acontece com as cores hexadecimal de 3 dígitos?

Tags: hexadecimal, cores

Eu sempre tive a curiosidade de saber o que acontece numa expressão hexadecimal de 3 dígitos de uma cor em CSS.

Por exemplo, você tem `000` e `000000`, que é a cor preta. E `fff` ou `ffffff` que é branco. Também há outras cores que é `F00` que é vermelho.

Porém resta uma curiosidade:

- Como eu traduziria essa cor hexadecimal de 3 dígitos para o de 6 dígitos?
- Tem alguma fórmula para transformar hexadecimal de cor de 3 para 6?

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar : https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-color-20010305#colorunits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme a documentação da `W3C` sobre [unidades de cores](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-color-20010305#colorunits), os valores numéricos `RGB` são representandos por notação hexadecimal, precedido do caractere `#`.

Eles podem conter `3`ou `6` dígitos, sendo representados da seguinte maneira:

```
EM { color: #f00 }              /* #rgb */
EM { color: #ff0000 }           /* #rrggbb */
```

O que acontece quando se usa apenas três dígitos, é a replicação deles na fórmula `rrggbb`, sendo assim, o valor `#fb0` tem seus caracteres replicados e expandidos para `#ffbb00`.

**OBS**: Há quem pense que o valor de três dígitos são preenchido com zeros para completar o valor `hexadecimal` de seis dígitos, e isto é um grande equívoco!

@edit

> Como eu traduziria essa cor hexadecimal de 3 dígitos para o de 6 dígitos?

Conforme explicado anteriormente, basta replicar os caracteres, por exemplo: `fb0` torna-se: `ff`, `bb` e `00` respectivamente, formando o código: `ffbb00`.

> Tem alguma fórmula para transformar hexadecimal de cor de 3 para 6?

Não há nenhuma fórmula específica para esse "esquema", o próprio navegador se encarrega da replicação, mas se for para um caso de uso específico, você pode implementar a replicação da maneira que desejar.

Comment: eu também pensava que era preenchido com zeros

Comment: Exato, @WallaceMaxters. É um equívoco comum, e que passa despercebido na maioria das vezes.

Answer (score 7):

As cores hexadecimais de 3 dígitos são expandidas dobrando cada caractere (veja [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-color-20010305#colorunits)).

Assim o código `#F3A` é transformado para `#FF33AA`.

Traduzido de https://stackoverflow.com/a/10230746/5230740.

Comment: Como assim "...são expandidas do branco cada caractere"?

Comment: Erro de ortografia corrigido: dobrando cada caractere

Comment: @MurilloGoulart kkkkkkk

Comment: kkkkkkk agora entendi

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade Certo!! Uma edição de terceiro ainda piorou o erro. Mas beleza, o que vale é a intenção! hauhau

Answer (score 2):

É simples, leia-se assim.

```
Para #000 - RGB

Para #000000 - RRGGBB
```